# What is the best practice for Angular 8 Interface + .Net Core Web API Project?

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core, webapi

Should I make different folder for angular 8 SPA app and another folder/project for .net core web API ?

Or is there a way to include one inside the another?

Or what is the best practice for this type of application?

Comment: my recommendation is keep fronted and backed as separate projects. you can use VSCode for fronted development and Visualstudio for backed development . its really easy for maintain your project in future

Answer (score 1):

I generally do my projects seperately but when I publish them put in same folder as parent child. Also you can do continious integration with this architecture. My projects are integrated to continious integration such as Parent as api wwwroot folder as angular project.

You can put angular project under core api wwwroot folder or you can put you core api under your angular project.

Base API CORE > wwwroot folder Angular Project

1) create `wwwroot` in api project if not exists

2) in startup allow `app.UseDefaultFiles(); app.UseStaticFiles();`

3) prod your angular `ng  build --prod`

4) put you angular dist inside to this `wwwroot` folder

Comment: I have not gone far into learning angular and core api as of now and doesn't know about the ng build process either. I think I need to learn more of them to understand your answer properly. Thanks.

Comment: ng build is to build project if you add --prod you build project as production then you can user created folder for website. It is a kind of publish project in .net.